# An inequality of three positive variables

Tags: inequality

Suppose that $x,y,z>0$ and $xyz=1$. Why does the inequality $$\frac{1}{x+y+1}+\frac{1}{y+z+1}+\frac{1}{x+z+1}\leq 1$$ holds? I couldn't see anything useful as I tried Jensen's inequality and calculus methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

If $a,b$ and $c$ be positive then
$$\frac{1}{{{a}^{3}}+{{b}^{3}}+abc}+\frac{1}{{{b}^{3}}+{{c}^{3}}+abc}+\frac{1}{{{c}^{3}}+{{a}^{3}}+abc}\le \frac{1}{abc}$$
set
$$a=\sqrt[3]{x}\quad,\quad b=\sqrt[3]{y}\quad,\quad c=\sqrt[3]{z}$$
**Edit**
$$I=\frac{1}{{{a}^{3}}+{{b}^{3}}+abc}\le \frac{1}{a^2b+b^2a+abc}$$
$$J=\frac{1}{{{b}^{3}}+{{c}^{3}}+abc}\le \frac{1}{b^2c+c^2b+abc}$$
$$K=\frac{1}{{{c}^{3}}+{{a}^{3}}+abc}\le \frac{1}{c^2a+a^2c+abc}$$
we have
$$I+J+K\le\frac{1}{a^2b+b^2a+abc}+\frac{1}{b^2c+c^2b+abc}+\frac{1}{c^2a+a^2c+abc}$$
$$I+J+K\le\frac{1}{a+b+c}\left(\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ca}\right)$$
$$I+J+K\le\frac{1}{abc}$$

Comment: I'm not really sure about this. It looks like you just set $a^3=x,b^3=y,c^3=z$ and watched how it modifies the inequality. Is the inequality you got a well known? It is new for me and I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Your Inequality is not  homogeneous but mine is a homogeneous inequality.

Comment: This is a first step. Now to the proof...